# Why calling conventions aren't used in all C programs

Tags: c, winapi, calling-convention

I am new to programming and while reading Charles Petzold book *Programming Windows*, I stumbled upon WINAPI (actually was surprised by the presence of another word before a function's name besides the return type) and found that it is a *calling convention* and to the best of my understanding it is a way of how a function pushes variables on the stack and gets the return value, I wondered why we do not use them in every C programs? Are they just exclusive to OS programming?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling conventions are typically tied to compiler, architecture and (when it comes to using system runtime libraries) the OS; they're not part of the C standard at all. In most cases, there's only one calling convention for a given architecture/compiler/OS combo, so you don't need to think about it; it just uses the only convention that OS supports.

The one place where it has mattered a lot in recent history was on 32 bit x86 systems, particularly on Windows. x86 had very few general purpose registers, so only a few were available at all, less than what a typical function might need for its arguments, and using them for argument passing meant you often needed to push whatever they used to contain to the stack, so there were a lot of trade-offs involved in calling conventions (it's faster to pass arguments in registers, but only if the caller could spare the registers or at least not be forced into excessive spilling to stack), and Windows went with "we'll use 'em all in different scenarios".

In modern usage on x86-64 (which is far less register starved) and on non-x86 architectures (which usually had enough registers), most compilers/OSes stick with a single common calling convention, so again, you don't need to pay attention. It's a curiosity, not something you need to personally pay attention to unless you're hand-writing whole functions in assembly.

Answer (score 2):

We DO use calling conventions in all C programs, but they are typically *defaulted* in the compiler settings and so do not have to be expressed *explicitly* in code, unless actually necessary (library interactions, etc).

Calling conventions are not part of the C language itself, but are handled by compiler vendors as extensions to the language.

Most C compilers typically default to the `__cdecl` calling convention, but this can be changed by the compiler user if needed.  Once upon a time, Windows APIs *used* to use `__pascal`, but for a *very long* time now `__stdcall` is being used instead.  Hence the existence of the `WINAPI` preprocessor macro so Microsoft could switch between them without requiring most existing code to be rewritten.

Comment: Note that the keywords `__cdecl` and `__stdcall` only represent different calling conventions when compiling a 32-bit program. When compiling a 64-bit program, these two keywords are identical; they both represent the same calling convention (which is different from the 32-bit calling conventions).

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Well, more accurately, in 64bit, calling convention keywords are simply ignored altogether, and the compiler itself implements the necessary calling convention for the platform being compiled for.

Comment: "Well, more accurately, in 64bit, calling convention keywords are simply ignored altogether" -- That statement is correct for the `__cdecl` and `__stdcall` keywords, but not for the [`__vectorcall`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/vectorcall) keyword. That keyword is not ignored when targetting the x64 platform. It represents a valid alternate x64 calling convention.